# It's possible navigate to route without showing params in url?

Tags: angular

I developing web app with angular 4 and I have a problem with my params in url.

I have 5 fields, one of these is a base64 image, but when I call my component in the url show all params, is possible not show these? Because when I do click in my browser to write url is very slow, because there is a base64 code.

Comment: If you don't want data to show in the URL, don't pass it as route parameter. Either use a shared service or use a resolver.

Comment: localstorage might help too, depending on your application. (cookies or session variables)

Comment: You should read Victor Savkin's blog post about state management in angular applications (https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b) because if you don't set the base64 of your image in url, it'll not be persistent with deep linking, so you have to take your parameters and find a solution based on this blog post I think.

Comment: Further detail on a shared service as mentioned in the comment from @GünterZöchbauer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular/10836/sharing-data-among-components#t=201707280041088605019). Although as Supamiu mentioned, you may want to have some resource ID along with that so that your application can fetch the picture based on data in the URL. [This blog post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) is useful for route resolvers

Comment: I am reading and the solution correct is shared service, but I don't know implement this, any idea?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

At it's absolute simplest you can use a service which has a public value:

```js
@Injectable()
export class Base64Share {
  image: string
}
```

(Although in many cases a [`Subject`](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) that can stream changes to components as the value changes is preferable)

You can then set the image in the parent:

```js
constructor(private imageShare: Base64Share) {
  this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
}

setImage() {
  this.imageShare.image = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
}
```

And get it in the child:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.image = "data:image/png;base64, " + this.imageShare.image;
}
```

child template

```html
<img [src]="image | safeUrl"/>
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wyjHBxktL4FPSqtnkGzJ?p=preview)

Comment: I have a question with your solution, why you add a Pipe? Thanks, this is my solution maybe!

Comment: Just because I think it is simpler than using the DomSanitizer in the component - personal preference

Comment: Is that in all my implementation I have not used any of that you say, explain me please?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific please?

Comment: DomSanitizer...in a moment I see that error, but in my constructor I do `this.foto = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.foto.toString()` and work fine (I see the image) and error disappeared

Comment: Do you mean why is the DomSanitizer necessary?

Comment: Because without it you can get an error from Angular when you are setting the `src` of an image: see [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2) for more detail

Comment: Bro, your code not work to image, return me WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding.

Comment: are you using `[src]` the way that I did in the example? You can refer to the plunker I created to see the difference - it is working correctly

Comment: I obtain an error, `compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{foto|dataTableDetail}}] in ng:///AppModule/DataTableDetailComponent.html@74:14 ("          style="float:center;width:100%; height:100%; max-height:80%; max-width:80%"
              [ERROR ->][src]={{foto|dataTableDetail}}/>`

Comment: Also remove the `{{}}` when adding square brackets to `[src]` see [this helpful guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) for more detail

Comment: No, and not really relevant, but if you're looking for Him you could try [reading more like this](http://biblehub.com/john/3-16.htm). You're welcome though