# How to convert base64 to image file for sharing on facebook or twitter - TypeScript ionic3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

[base64 file get from strorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM1RO.png)

how to convert base64 to image file (jpeg) for sharing

on Instagram base64 it's working but Facebook and Twitter not working

How to solve it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2/38813115)