# how to render image in angular from server in Angular?

Tags: angular

i have a spring boot backend ... made a service that returns a byte array image .. 
how to receive it in Angular and render it...

here's my angular code :

```
getFile(id) {
const _loadFileByIdUrl = environment.baseUrl + `finance/api/getFile`;
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('id', id);
return this.http.post<any>(_loadFileByIdUrl, fd
 );
}
```

i'm trying to console.log() the resoponse is 200 but i got error message : message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/finance/api/getFile"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BASE64 to image angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2)

Comment: is base64 the best format to load an image from a server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you indicate that a different response type is expected, the http client attempts to parse the response as JSON. Use the responseType `blob` for binary data:

```
this.http.post(_loadFileByIdUrl, fd, { responseType: 'blob' });
```

Given that you have an image tag in your template, such as:

```
<img #smartesImage />
```

You could then access the image in your template like so

```
@ViewChild('smartesImage') smartesImage: ElementRef<any>;
```

And actually display the binary data using the following code:

```
this.http.post(_loadFileByIdUrl, fd, { responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(res => {
   const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
   this.smartesImage.nativeElement.src = objectURL;
});
```

Comment: when putting this line : 
this.http.post<any>(_loadFileByIdUrl, fd, { responseType: 'blob' });
 
i get this error : Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"