# Display image via Typescript model in Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have a profile page in my `Angular` (v8) project and normally I use the following approach in order to display user photo:

```
<img class="profile-user-img" src="./DemoController/GetPhoto?Id={{rec.Id}}" />
```

However, I think there is another way to bind the image via `model.ts` that is already filled from database as the other fields. By doing this I just send a single request to the database instead of twice and the photo data will be included in the `model.ts`. So, how can I do this? Should I need a special convert image data before rendering?

***Note:*** I use `byte[]` as the data type of photo on `C#` side. Any idea?

Here is my model. ts below:

```
export interface IUserProfile {
    Id: number;
    Photo: string | ArrayBuffer;
    NameSurname: string;
}
```

Comment: There are many similar questions : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use the byte array to fill the `img.src` attribute.
In your template to the component you can write as follows:

```
<img class="profile-user-img" src="data:image/gif;base64,{{Profile.Photo}}" />
```

Where in your component you have:

```
@Component({})
export class User {
  Profile: UserProfile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, seems to be quickest way but I encountered "*GET unsafe:data:image/gif;base64, ... net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"*

Comment: Why is there an error. I think it is a normal method to display an image in html. Did the http request already happen on `UserProfile` instantiation?

Comment: Ok, now fixed after you updated your answer. Voted up, many thanks ;)