# src property binding not working in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, property-binding

I have two urls for two different images, on one the [src] property binding is working while on the other one it is not.
What can possibly be the reason?

works:

```
<img [src]="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png" />
```

doesn't work:

```
<img [src]="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==" />
```

Comment: You need to share your code

Comment: Any warn in console?

Comment: can u make some test? tell us the result. Maybe the console output an error, the url works independently without been a src?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813115/6851836

Answer (score 1):

why do you use `[src]` simple use `src`

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==" />
```

Even you first case will not work [check this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvtbw6)

You `[src]` where your source link is defined in you component like `[src]="somecomponentproperty"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

In component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//This is required
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  //Constructor Required
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
  }

  //Call this method in the image source, it will sanitize it.
    transform(){
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.base64Image);
  }

  base64Image='data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD.......';


}
```

In Html

```
<img [src]="transform()">
```