# Angular: importing images as typescript modules

Tags: angular, typescript

In React (CRA), the following works: `import logo from './logo.png';`. However when I try this in Angular (12) I get the error `Cannot find module './logo.png' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I know the "angular way" is to make use of assets, however this doesn't work for me, since I'm creating an Angular library, which has no assets.

How can I make the above work or what are alternative solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the image to a base64 string. However when using this directly in the `src` I got an warning in the console about something to do with sanitizing.

After some searching, it turns out you need to sanitize your own resource strings using `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`. Thanks to [BASE64 to image angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2).

Some notes: Use DomSanitizer with care since there could some risks. Make sure the data is trusted.

Comment: This is not a right way to manage assests

Answer (score 1):

In angular you can use ng-packagr to copy assets in the library build folder. `ng-package.json` file is already available in your library root folder.

```js
  {
  "ngPackage": {
    "assets": [
      "CHANGELOG.md",
      "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
    ],
    "lib": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

see this link for more details: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md